# Why does Proxima Nova render strangely in select inputs?

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, rendering

In Chrome the Proxima Nova web font, which looks great everywhere else, renders very in strangely `select` dropdowns:

[image]

The characters in the option tags seem to be transposed with other, seemingly random, characters. The text in the drop down itself renders correctly once the option has been selected.

Does anyone know the reason for this behaviour, and is there a resolution?

Comment: Do you have a site where we can see this in action?

Comment: [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15010029/chrome-jumbles-text-styled-with-a-web-font-in-svg-format-sometimes) and [this Chromium bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=95102).  It's just a rendering bug that's gone unfixed for a terribly long time.